# Multibody Dynamics - Modeling joints - Spherical verses Gimbal

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

I am working through a rigid multibody dynamics problem using this paper as a reference: [Newton-Euler Dynamic Equations of Motion for a Multi-body Spacecraft](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20080044854/downloads/20080044854.pdf). I am trying to understand the differences in modeling a spherical joint or a gimballed joint or even a more simplified pin joint.  Wouldn't a spherical joint and a gimballed joint both have 3 degrees of freedom, ie rotation around $x_1, x_2, x_3$ axis, and therefore the relationship between the motion of an inner and outer body surrounding a joint could be derived the same way.  The author of the paper lays out two different methods for an $N$-body problem and treats the joints differently stating "The gimballed joint formulation starts from a more advantageous position, in that the redundant velocity and angular velocity states have already been reduced by combination into the gimbal angular rates"  How does the gimbal angular rates differ from the direction cosines relating the body frames of reference to one another?

Perhaps another way to phase this question is what is the difference between the direction cosine matrix transforming characteristics expressed in the X or Y frame (these frames being fixed body frames) and the matrix of nonlinear gimbal angles about a 'space' or 'body' axis?

Further looking at a pin joint having only 1 rotational degree of freedom - could this then be modeled by restricting the spherical or gimballed models to only 1 rotational degree of freedom?

Comment: I guess that the main difference is only about the coordinates used for modelling the components, with the gimbal component readily providing some angles used (and of interest) in applications. BTW, it looks like you're referring to quite an outdated paper. If you will deal with multibody dynamics for a while, I'd suggest to have a look at MBDyn, multibody code developed at the Politecnico di Milano, and the documentation you can find at their webpage https://www.mbdyn.org/Documentation/Documentation.html

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but using another code is not an option I would like to explore at this time.  Yes this paper is from 2007 - if you have a newer better paper you'd suggest I'll check it out :) thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but my account was suspended for a week. My suggestion was not about changing code, but taking a look at the theory manual of the code with lots of details about the analytical formulation of components and constraints

Comment: Aww I see.  I'll take a look at the theory manual - thanks!